# Sql Server - FULL JOIN splitting up the result rather than returning a joined dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Suppose I have the following (very simplified) schema / data set up in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #Ids1 (Id1 VARCHAR(1));
CREATE TABLE #Vals1 (Id1 VARCHAR(1), Id2 VARCHAR(1));

CREATE TABLE #Ids2 (Id1 VARCHAR(1));
CREATE TABLE #Vals2 (Id1 VARCHAR(1), Id2 VARCHAR(1));

INSERT INTO #Ids1 (Id1) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d');
INSERT INTO #Vals1 (Id1, Id2) VALUES ('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4');

INSERT INTO #Ids2 (Id1) VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('e'), ('f'), ('g');
INSERT INTO #Vals2 (Id1, Id2) VALUES ('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3'), ('e', '5'), ('f', '6'), ('g', '7');
```

Basically, I have 2 similar datasets - One ending with a `1` suffix, the other ending with a `2` suffix and there is a chance either of the datasets may have data that is not in the other set.

What I would like to do is create a query that returns a single joined dataset that would look as follows:

```
#Ids1.Id1   #vals1.Id1  #vals1.Id2  #Ids2.Id1   #Vals2.Id1  #Vals2.Id2
a           a           1           a           a           1
b           b           2           b           b           2
c           c           3           c           c           3
d           d           4           NULL        NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        e           e           5
NULL        NULL        NULL        f           f           6
NULL        NULL        NULL        g           g           7
```

I figured the following SQL would accomplish this:

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
    #Ids1
    FULL JOIN #Vals1
    ON #Vals1.Id1 = #Ids1.Id1
    FULL JOIN #Ids2
    ON #Ids2.Id1 = #Ids1.Id1
    FULL JOIN #Vals2
    ON #Vals2.Id1 = #Ids2.Id1
    AND #Vals2.Id2 = #Vals1.Id2
```

but it is separating out the last tables rather than joining them, so it ends up looking as follows:

```
#Ids1.Id1   #vals1.Id1  #vals1.Id2  #Ids2.Id1   #Vals2.Id1  #Vals2.Id2
a           a           1           a           a           1
b           b           2           b           b           2
c           c           3           c           c           3
d           d           4           NULL        NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        e           NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        f           NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        g           NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        e           5
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        f           6
NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        g           7
```

I've created a link to the prepared Schema and the SQL at the following URL:
http://rextester.com/SAX53638

I'm guessing / **hoping** I'm just missing something simple, but I just can't seem to get it to work. What's the best way to return the data I want?

Comment: Don't have time to write out the full query, but you could create two sub-queries, one which inner joins the id1 and val1 tables, and the other that inner joins the id2 and val2 tables. Then you could full join those two subqueroes together.

Comment: Thanks so much, @digital.aaron. I also thought of that, was just hoping for a cleaner solution than having to split the tables up... Any other thoughts or is that definitely the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Join the tables internally and then join again

Try using the below the query
SELECT
     *
FROM
    (SELECT
    Ids1.Id1 AS Id11,
     vals1.Id1 AS Idv11,
     vals1.Id2 AS Idv12
     FROM
    Ids1
    FULL JOIN Vals1
    ON Vals1.Id1 = Ids1.Id1) Ivs1
    FULL JOIN
    (SELECT
     Ids2.Id1 AS Id21,
     vals2.Id1 AS Idv21,
     vals2.Id2 AS Idv22
    FROM
    Ids2
    FULL JOIN Vals2
    ON Vals2.Id1 = Ids2.Id1) Ivs2
    ON Ivs1.Id11 = Ivs2.Id21;

Comment: This is the query for what "digital.aaron" said

Comment: Thanks so much! I also thought of that as a solution - Is that really the best way to do it? It felt kind of clunky, but it definitely works... I was just hoping to be able to do everything in a single join, but, if it's not possible, then so be it!

Comment: You can add an and condition in the join that both ids1.id1 and ids2.id1 cannot be null at the same time